# Paginação de consulta com função LIKE

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, query, offset

boa tarde. Estou com um erro na consulta com paginação quando eu passo um parâmetro de pesquisa. Segue o problema: Quando estou na pagina 2 e faço uma pesquisa por um item que esta na pagina 20 meu `sql` não retorna nada. Segue o `sql`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela
 WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE UPPER(‘%cadern%’)
 LIMIT 10
OFFSET (2 - 1) * 10
```

Esse `LIKE` retorna duas linhas, mas o `OFFSET` está para retornar a partir da linha 10 então sempre vem vazio.

Alguém já teve este problema?

Comment: Não entendi seu problema. Você, por acaso, quer dizer que em toda sua tabela existem apenas 2 linhas que atendem  à condição expressa na cláusula WHERE?  Se for isso então seu OFFSET está correto. O LIMIT e OFFSET se aplicam ao resultado do SELECT.

Comment: Isso com esse LIKE so retorna duas linhas, mas por eu estar na pagina 2 da minha aplicação web o calculo do OFFSET fica errado. Pois quando eu uso esse mesmo filtro na pagina 1 da aplicação web o calculo do OFFSET funciona. O calculo que eu uso é esse: (pageSize * (page -1))

Comment: Então o problema não está com o PostgreSQL e sim com sua aplicação que não deve estar utilizando o valor correto no comando SQL.